# install pljava on Windows 7 with Postgres 9.6

Tags: postgresql, pljava

I am struggling to install pljava on Windows 7 Sp1 with Postgres 9.6.

When I run the following command:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sqlj.java_call_handler()
RETURNS language_handler AS 'pljava'
LANGUAGE C;
```

I receive the following error:

> ERROR: could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/lib/pljava.dll": The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: So, how did you install PL/java?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be necessary at all to create the `java_call_handler` manually and such. The [installation procedure](http://tada.github.io/pljava/install/install.html) changed with PL/Java 1.5.0 so you simply get a self-extracting jar that you run (with `java -jar`*jarname*) and then in `psql` you say `CREATE EXTENSION pljava;` and it's ready to use. (You may have to set one variable to the location of your Java runtime. Details in the installation docs.)

That said, PostgreSQL 9.6 has some problems with PL/Java 1.5.0 (9.5 works fine). PL/Java 1.5.1 will do 9.6, but it's not quite out yet. You can build from the tip of the [REL1_5_STABLE branch](https://github.com/tada/pljava/tree/REL1_5_STABLE) if you do such things.